# Problem with TableOfContents whith XeLaTex+ucharclasses+Babel

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, babel, greek, ucharclasses

I want to write a greek-english text. I am using babel+XeLaTex. I have a problem with the table of contents: When these lines are included in my code

```
\setDefaultTransitions{\selectlanguage{english}}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\setTransitionTo{GreekAndCoptic}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
```

it produces the following error:

> "LaTeX Error: Command \rmfamily invalid in math mode.    output.toc, line
> 67"

and a warning at the *' \tableofcontents '* command, mentioning:

> Package babel Warning: \englishcontentsname not set. Please, define it after the language has been loaded (typically in the preamble) with something like: \renewcommand\englishcontentsname{..} Reported on input line 23.

In the pdf, instead of *' Contents '* at the start of the ToC, it has *' ?contentsname? '*

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}

\babelprovide{greek,english}
\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures={Common,Rare}, Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont{sf}[Ligatures={Common,Rare}]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}{Libertinus Mono}

\babelfont[Language=greek]{rm}{Kerkis}
\babelfont[Language=greek]{sf}{Kerkis}
\babelfont[Language=greek]{tt}{kerkis}

\setDefaultTransitions{\selectlanguage{english}}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\setTransitionTo{GreekAndCoptic}{\selectlanguage{greek}} 

\begin{document}
some text
blabla μπλαμπλα

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Introduction-Εισαγωγή}

\subsection{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: wrt `babel`, load the package with `\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}`, remove the line with `\babelprovide`, remove `Language=` in `\babelfont` so that the result is something like `\babelfont[greek]{rm}{Kerkis}`. Some problems related to `ucharclasses` remain, but I don't use it, so I'm not sure how to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Need further clarification on what you want to achieve.

When I make Greek the main language in babel, and set the fonts for the transitions (making Greek blue, to show which font made it into the table of contents), the TOC is OK.

[image: Greek TOC]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\defaultfont}{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{Kerkis}[Colour=blue]
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\setDefaultTransitions{\defaultfont}{}
\setTransitionsForGreek{\greekfont}{}
%\babelprovide{greek,english}
%\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures={Common,Rare}, Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
%\babelfont{sf}[Ligatures={Common,Rare}]{Libertinus Sans}
%\babelfont{tt}{Libertinus Mono}
%
%\babelfont[Language=greek]{rm}{Kerkis}
%\babelfont[Language=greek]{sf}{Kerkis}
%\babelfont[Language=greek]{tt}{kerkis}

%\setDefaultTransitions{\selectlanguage{english}}{\selectlanguage{english}}
%\setTransitionTo{GreekAndCoptic}{\selectlanguage{greek}} 

\begin{document}
some text
blabla μπλαμπλα

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Introduction-Εισαγωγή}

\subsection{test}

\end{document}
```